# Checking cookies on other pages

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, isset

I am having trouble setting and checking cookies in PHP.  What I would like to do is set a cookie on one page and on another page, check to see if that cookie exists.

On the first page, I set the cookie using:

```
setcookie ("conversionChecker", "anything", time() - 3600);
```

and on the 2nd page, I check if that cookie is set using:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['conversionChecker'])){
  // include conversion code
}else{
  // dont include conversion code
}
```

However when I check for the cookie, it always returns false.

Answer (score 3):

The cookie is false because you are setting an expire time that has already passed.  Try adding a plus instead of minus:

```
setcookie ("conversionChecker", "anything", time() + 3600);
```

time() is the current timestamp and 3600 is 1 hour.  So it will expire one hour after it is set.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting a cookie to a time in the past.. this is effectively the same as deleting a cookie.